# Requests.get failing when using inside function

Tags: python, authentication, get, python-requests

I am using python requests library to get the data from [adzuna api](https://developer.adzuna.com/overview) .

if i try

```
r = requests.get("http://api.adzuna.com/v1/api/jobs/gb/search/1?app_id=appID\
    &app_key=appKEY&results_per_page=50&\
    what=entry%20level&content-type=application/json")
print r.text
```

it is fetching me data
But if i wrap this inside a fuction

```
def getData ():
    r = requests.get("http://api.adzuna.com/v1/api/jobs/gb/search/1?app_id=appID\
    &app_key=appKey&results_per_page=50&\
    what=entry%20level&content-type=application/json")
    print r.text

getData()
```

it is giving me following exception

```
{"display":"Authorisation failed","__CLASS__":"Adzuna::API::Response::Exception","doc":"http://api.adzuna.com/v1/doc","exception":"AUTH_FAIL"}
```

what is the wrong with this function ?

[See the Image for more info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqiji.png)

Comment: You've missed a slash in the 2nd url (`.../search 1?...`)

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing it out, it is copy paste mistake, i edited queston

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ not a duplicate, at least not a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @t.m.adam Really? Won't converting `print(r.text)` to `return r.text` solve OP's problem?

Comment: @COLDSPEED why it is duplicate ? It is entirely different question - if not please explain

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ OP gets a response anyway, but it's en error response.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ No - It wont solve the problem

Comment: Oops, reopened. Carry on.

Comment: @anilkunchala i don't see why the 2nd case returns a different response. Please make sure that you have the same url or any other parameters.

Comment: seems like you need an app_key and app_id in order to make api request

Comment: @t.m.adam both url's are same , 
Do you think the problem is with AUTH ?
i tried to pass them as headers - but it's not successful.

Comment: @ddor254 i am passing both app_key and app_id.

Comment: @t.m.adam please check the image for more info

Comment: Both urls look identical, so the response should be the same. The only think that think of is the line breaks. Can you try again with the url in a single line?

Comment: show us the app key and id that we could try on our own

Comment: @t.m.adam url in single line is working

Comment: Cool, case closed!

Comment: thanks, can you make that as answer ? so i can mark it as answered ?

Comment: You could accept @NathanVērzemnieks answer bellow, it's the proper way to request GET parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(edited) Since using a single-line query fixed your problem, I'll recommend that you don't try to build the query yourself but instead let requests do it for you, like so:

```
query = {'app_id': 'appID',
         'app_key': 'appKey',
         'content-type': 'application/json',
         'results_per_page': '50',
         'what': 'entry level'}
r = requests.get('http://api.adzuna.com/v1/api/jobs/gb/search/1', params=query)
```

This should be less error-prone and is certainly more convenient.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, that's just a copy paste mistake - i edited question

Answer (score 0):

In the second url you have a sapce between `gb/search/` and the `1` after him.

Comment: thanks for noticing (edited question)- that's a another copy paste error. the url is working but authorization is failing i.e getting an AUTH_FAIL Exception

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with a POST call and learned that problem was with formatting the text I was passing, some APIs can't handle any change on the format. inside function you have extra indentation and that messes up what I was posting.
Instead of passing simple string:

- Pass parameters in a json format if possible
- Have all in one line
- Reformat and print the string and make sure they look exactly the same in and out of function.